# Double clicking on a cell in Excel, open source file of that line on userform

Tags: excel, userform, worksheet, vba

I am trying something and I don't even know if it's possible.

I have about 20 progress reports of projects. These projects are being updated by users that use a userform. 
Once a week, I have a few macros running  that goes to each of them, copy the data and put them in a Project Summary that is in a different workbook. What I want is to be able to double click on the first cell in any given row( there's about 200 projects) in that Project Summary workbook and that opens that specific project in the already existing userform that the users are using. But I want it to open it at the source file not in the data dump of the Project Summary worksheet.

Is there a way I can do this?

EDIT:

I have tried this:

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Cell As Range

If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
Else
For Each Cell In Range("E:E")
    If (Cell.Value = "A, B") Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
            "filepath", Password:="...", ReadOnly:=True
        progressReport.Show

    End If
 Next Cell
 End If

 End Sub
```

I willdo that for each of the 20 other progress report based on the value of Range(E:E). What I want is that when it open the file to load the userform, it load the specific report for the value in A

Comment: Show what you tried, explain your data, what is in "the first cell in any given row"...

Comment: @phil652 I have edited the code. Please let me know if this make more sense

Comment: Regarding `For Each Cell In Range("E:E")` do you **really** want to try to open 1,048,576 workbooks? Seems a little excessive to me.

Comment: @Jeeped you are right... I was just not sure how to do it. I have tried your code below and it is partially working. How Do I load only the data of that row A that was double clicked on in the userform?

Comment: To expand on what I stated in my answer below, if you want to put the value from column E into Textbox1 then `Textbox1.value = cells(target.row, "E").value`. However, I do not see what this has to do with opening a workbook.

Comment: @Jeeped I didnt express myself right... I don't want to put value E in the a textbox of the userform...  I have 20 different workbooks... each of them has between 10-20 projects organized by row. Each workbook has the same userform allowing the user to update existing information. This information is then Copy/Pasted into a Summary Project Workbook. In that Summary Project Workbook, I want to be able to double click on A (project number) then based on the value of E(project leader, the user) open the right workbook and load that specific project that was double clicked on

Comment: @Jeeped The reason i want to do this is because the Project Summary is being supervised by the Director of the whole thing, he wants to be able to see a quick summary(only a few fields were copie on the Summary Project Workbook). But he also wants to be able to see the whole project that the users see and change or add comment in these projects. So I want to be able to open the source file of that project when he double click on a project number, load that specific project in the userform

Comment: Sorry but I believe I have offered all of the generalities I can and you will need to interpret what I have offered. If the workbook file name and path is in column E then open `cells(target.row, "E").value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick event macro and Cancel any possible 'in-cell' editing before it happens.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.UsedRange, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        'cancel 'in-cell editing'
        Cancel = True

        'load your user form here using target.row
        'example: cells(target.row, "E").value is the value from
        '         column E on the same row as the double-click
        debug.print Target.Row

    End If
End Sub
```

You can only double-click a single cell so multiple cells as Target are not a possibility.

This belongs in the worksheet's code sheet (e.g. right-click name tab, View Code); not a standard module code sheet.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you code does. Do you mind helping me understand.

Comment: If you double-click a cell then it triggers (aka runs). If the cell you double-clicked is within the used range of the worksheet and in column A then it cancels the 'in-cell-editing' and runs the rest of the code. I've shown where and how to load your userform with values from the row that had column A double-clicked.